# Save all buffers content in weechat

Tags: weechat

How can i save all what has been written in a private buffer?
Also is there a possibility to re open the same layout(including buffers) after exit?
/set weechat.look.save_config_on_exit all

Doesn't seem to do what it's suggesting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Weechat already logs buffer content to file by default. See the [logger plugin section in the docs](https://weechat.org/files/doc/stable/weechat_user.en.html#logger_plugin).

`logger.file.auto_log`: automatically save content of buffers to files (unless a buffer disables log) [ default: on ]

`logger.file.path`: path of WeeChat log files

Logs are found at `~/.weechat/logs/` by default, one file per buffer.

Comment: This is just a text log, which you can't re-open into weechat. Afaik, there is no way to do what the original question asks, which is top re-open the buffers back in weechat after closing it. You have to parse the log files manually and view them in a text editor (less, gedit, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Another "workaroud"-answer to the question "how to get information from the previous logs" from within WeeChat is:
 install the `grep.py` plugin (`/script install grep.py`).

1) With this plugin you can list the logs (filenames in ~/.weechat/logs) and their size with:

`/logs` 
(look at `/help logs` after installing "grep.py")

2) And you can `/grep` these logfile (or the current opened buffers if you like) with e.g.:
`/grep log *perl* CSV` 
(this looks in all logfile with perl: #perl, #perl6, #perl.de, ... for the string "CSV" and will list the occurrances)

see `/help grep` (after install of grep.py) - there are many options

(also: see this blog for information about logging https://blog.jeaye.com/2016/10/31/weechat-logs/)

Answer (score 0):

**Update WeeChat 4.0.4 (2023)**

*( Aug 22, 2023 ) Version 4.0. 4 is available!*

Log path:

```
 ~/.local/share/weechat/logs
```